# Hos can I add a column porcentaje based on other column in my data frame?

Tags: r, percentage, mutated

I would like to create a column in my data frame that gives the percentage of each category. The total (100%) would be the summary of the column Score.

My data looks like

```
Client  Score
  <chr> <int>
1 RP      125
2 DM      30
```

Expected

```
Client  Score    %
  <chr> <int>
1 RP      125    80.6
2 DM      30     19.3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note special character in column names is not good.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(`%` = round(Score/sum(Score, na.rm = TRUE)*100, 1))
```

```
  Client Score    %
1     RP   125 80.6
2     DM    30 19.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to use dplyr.  I recreated your data below and used the mutate function to create a new column on the dataframe.

```
#Creation of data
Client <- c("RP","DM")
Score <- c(125,30)
DF <- data.frame(Client,Score)
DF

#install.packages("dplyr") #Remove first # and install if library doesn't load
library(dplyr)  #If this doesn't run, install library using code above.

#Shows new column
DF %>% 
  mutate("%" = round((Score/sum(Score))*100,1))

#Overwrites dataframe with new column added
DF %>% 
  mutate("%" = round((Score/sum(Score))*100,1)) -> DF
```

Using base R functions the same goal can be achieved.

```
X <- round((DF$Score/sum(DF$Score))*100,1) #Creation of percentage
DF$"%" <- X #Storage of X as % to dataframe
DF #Check to see it exists
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, may use `proportions`

```
df[["%"]] <-  round(proportions(df$Score) * 100, 1)
```

-output

```
> df
  Client Score    %
1     RP   125 80.6
2     DM    30 19.4
```

Comment: @TarJae I see some comments from legends like Frank there.  It may be better to use their advice